Bike helmet not small enough
After an MTB helmet, measured my head at 49-50cm and all helmets I can find that have the safety features I'm after (mainly MIPTS) start at 51 cm.. what do I do ? as not even google can help

Go to a large LBS bike shop and try helmets on. Heads come in different shapes as well as sizes, the only way to be sure a helmet will fit you well is to try it on.
Where I live, helmets are compulsory, so there is a wide range of helmet sizes to suit children of all ages. If not compulsory, you can probably still find a shop with a good range of helmets for kids. There are plenty of children's (tweenagers and teenagers) into serious MTBing, so good helmets in small sizes are readily available. While many 'kids' helmets are 'kid themed', there are still plenty that look no different to what an adult would wear.
If the only choice I had that fitted well was a pink unicorn themed helmet or none at all, I would be happy to wear a pink unicorn themed helmet. (Although I doubt anyone makes a unicorn themed MIPS helmet)
As far as MIPS- I personally would choose a helmet that fitted well over a MIPS helmet that did not fit well. MIPS is an advancement, but it is not the be-all and end-all for bicycle helmets. All it says is MIPS is at least 10% better at dissipating rotational forces. The window that 10% makes a difference is small - below a point a non-MIPs will save you, at some point, even a MIPs helmet won't save you, and that 10% is only for rotational forces.   A poorly fitting helmet probably offer less overall protection than a well fitted one, especially if you are not wearing it because it is uncomfortable.
https://velo.outsideonline.com/road/road-gear/mips-the-reality-behind-making-helmets-safer/

I’d go to various online shops which sell bike helmets and filter for your head circumference. For example this is bike-components filtering for MTB helmets with 49 or 50cm head circumference.
https://www.bike-components.de/en/apparel/helmets/?filterApplication=MTB&filterHead%2520Circumference~~%2520cm%5B0%5D=49&filterHead%2520Circumference~~%2520cm%5B1%5D=50&sort=price_asc

